# node js module libxml xsd not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, libxml2, xsd-validation

I want to install to module libxml xsd.But when i run the command `npm install libxml-xsd` nothing happing.When i want to test my module i try to run

```
var xsd = require('libxml-xsd');
```

but i have this error :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'libxml-xsd'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\amine.brahmi\WebstormProjects\modeltestvalidation\test_validation.js:1:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

> node-gyp version 3.8.0
>    node version 10.16.3 
>   npm version 6.9.0

i try to install but i have the same error.

```
npm install libxmljs
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm install libxml-xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

node 10.X not compatible with libxml-xsd 0.5.2
you should install other version node 8.x for exemple :

then you need to install `nvm` to use the two node version from this link :

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

and then try `nvm list`  to show all node versions 
then  install new node version with `nvm 8.x 64` 
Next `nvm use 8.x 64` to switch to use 8.x